# Android - killing other app processes causes crash

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making an app to lock other apps, one process of this is to use a service which scans for activities from launching and if they are listed for locking, the process will be killed. (This is just the first step). I am testing my code and when I try to open an app that has been listed for locking, my app will crash along with its service. The activities which are listed for locking are listed in shared preferences with a boolean value of true if they are to be locked.

This method is implemented in a timer task scheduled to be ran every 1000ms:

```
    public void run() {


        //listen for apps opening
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);

        if (tasks != null && tasks.size() > 0) {
            String topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
            SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean Checked = settings.getBoolean(topActivity, false);

            if (Checked==true) {          //if topactivity is marked for locking
                 am.killBackgroundProcesses(topActivity); //this causes the crash
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any more information available, such as any stack information printed to Logcat when it crashes?

Comment: I'm not running the app in an emulator, I believe I can get logcat from my phone if I install some software, if so I will paste here

Comment: Run "adb logcat" from a command line with your phone connected. Or even better, run DDMS in your Android SDK tools folder.

Comment: I was missing <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />  from the manifest, however it still does not work as expected = it no longer crashes, but if I open up for example the clock activity it doesn't close when it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Comment: thanks I realised I had missed this, however the service still does not work as expected - it no longer crashes, but if I open up an activity that should be killed it doesn't close

Comment: I think it will only kill activities in the background.  If you open it, you will have to switch to another one and then wait for your timer task to run before it will close.